# Specifying Types of Parameters and Return Values in Python

Tags: python, types, parameters, return-type

I want to specify types in the function definition such as:

```
def foo(grid : List[List[str]]) -> int:
    return 0
```

However when I run it in the interpreter (3.7.6), it states ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "List". Does anyone have documentation as to where I can read more about specifying the types of parameters and return values?  How would I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2):

It's from the [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) module:

```
from typing import List


def foo(grid : List[List[str]]) -> int:
    return 0
```

See [`typing.List`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.List)

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I was looking for thank you!